# Инициализация Yandex Map по координатам прямого геокодирования

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Я получаю с сервера данные для прямого геокодирования (город+адрес):

```
var currAddress = "<?= $apart->region ?>"+"<?= $apart->address ?>";
```

Затем инициализирую карту:

```
function init() {

   var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
         center: [44,44],
         zoom: 7,
         controls: ["fullscreenControl"]
   });

   ymaps.geocode(currAddress, {
         results: 1
         }).then(function (res) {
                var firstGeoObject = res.geoObjects.get(0),

                coords = firstGeoObject.geometry.getCoordinates(),

                bounds = firstGeoObject.properties.get('boundedBy');


                myMap.geoObjects.add(firstGeoObject);

                myMap.setBounds(bounds, {

                          checkZoomRange: true
                });
         });
}
```

Мне не очень нравится, что карта инициализируется на [44,44] и затем "прыгает" по переданному адресу. Инициализировать карту без координат невозможно, и создать геокод до инициализации, очевидно, тоже. Есть ли "безкостыльные" способы инициализировать карту сразу на переданных данных?

Comment: Отправьте адрес на геокодер, джейсоном получите координаты и по ним инициализируйте. https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/geocoder/desc/examples/geocoder_examples-docpage/

Answer (score 0):

Хм, вопрос был достаточно глупым, поскольку я не заметил, что геокоды не привязаны к конкретной карте. Как @Jean-Claude и сказал, можно было просто получить координаты по геокодеру.